# Javascript added HTML value is removed when datepicker is selected

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a Bootstrap modal where you can select a date. In the background, hidden fields are populated that are also submitted with the form.

The issue is that when you select the `datepicker` element, it removes the hidden value for some strange reason (but only the hidden values populated by the Javascript).

**Datepicker JS:**

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: date,
    autoclose: true,
});
```

**Hidden field Populating JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#appointment').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
        $("#request_id").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('request-id'));
    });
});
```

**Hidden HTML element:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="request_id" id="request_id" value="">
```

When the Modal box initially pops up, I can see the hidden value field is populated, but when I click the `datepicker`, it's removed. Why is this?

Comment: grab and store form values with .val();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `show.bs.modal` is fired when bootstrap datepicker is opened. So you simply have to set `#request_id` value **only** when the `show.bs.modal` is related to modal opening. One way you can use to get the element that fired the event is checking `e.target.id` value inside your handler.

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  startDate: new Date(),
  autoclose: true,
});

$(function () {
  $('#appointment').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    if( e.target.id == 'appointment'){
      $("#request_id").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('request-id'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<input type="hidden" name="request_id" id="request_id" value="">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#appointment" data-request-id="myExampleId">
  Open appointment modal
</button>

<div id="appointment" class='modal fade'>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="datepicker">Date bootstrap</label>
          <input type="text" id="datepicker">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use trusted [Bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). If you using the same and making $ajax call, prevent extra values while making $ajax() by whilte listing your form values.

Comment: This is the one I'm using.