# 'hide.bs.modal' modal event is fired when clicking bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

As you can see, it's my first question, but not my first visit to stackoverflow. So please be patience if I do something wrong.

My problem is the following: I'm getting troubles with bootstrap-datepicker on a boostrap modal. I open a modal to edit some data, so I load the data on the modal using `'show.bs.modal'` event. One of the fields in the modal is the date of birth, where I use bootstrap-datepicker. The weird behavior starts when I click on the datepicker field. It fires the `'hide.bs.modal'` event, which I use to clean the data (reset validators and form) before closing the modal.

I've tried everything, I searched everywhere but still don't find what am I doing wrong. Plese help me!

I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.7 and Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.7.0

Here a snippet showing the issue:

```js
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '#editModal', function (e){
    alert("Why is this happening??!!!");
    $('#formEdit').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
    $('#formEdit')[0].reset();
});

$('#fecha_nac').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    language: 'es'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Ver y editar sacerdote</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form role="form" id="formEdit" action="" method="post">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label for="legajo">Legajo</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="legajo" name="legajo" placeholder="Ingrese legajo">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese apellido">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label for="fecha_nac">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fecha_nac" id="fecha_nac" placeholder="DD-MM-AAAA">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label class="control-label" for="pais_nac">Pa&iacute;s de nacimiento</label>
                <select name="pais_nac" class="form-control" id="pais_nac">
                    
                </select>
              </div>  
              <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label class="control-label" for="provincia_nac">Provincia de nacimiento</label>
                <select name="provincia_nac" class="form-control" id="provincia_nac">
                    
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label class="control-label" for="dpto_nac">Departamento de nacimiento</label>
                <select name="dpto_nac" class="form-control" id="dpto_nac">
                    
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-9">
                <label for="domicilio">Domicilio</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="domicilio" id="domicilio" placeholder="Ingrese domicilio">
              </div> 
              <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                <label for="cod_postal">C&oacute;digo postal</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cod_postal" id="cod_postal" placeholder="CP">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="pais_dom">Pa&iacute;s</label>
                <select name="pais_dom" class="form-control" id="pais_dom">
                   
                </select>
              </div>  
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="provincia_dom">Provincia</label>
                <select name="provincia_dom" class="form-control" id="provincia_dom">
                    
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="dpto_dom">Departamento</label>
                <select name="dpto_dom" class="form-control" id="dpto_dom">
                    
                </select>
              </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="sexo">Sexo</label>
                <select name="sexo" class="form-control" id="sexo">
                <option value="">-Seleccione sexo-</option>
                <option value="M" selected>Masculino</option>
                <option value="F">Femenino</option>
                
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="tipo_documento">Tipo documento</label>
                <select name="tipo_documento" class="form-control" id="tipo_documento">
                  
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="nro_documento">N&uacute;mero de documento</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nro_documento" id="nro_documento" placeholder="Ingrese documento">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="correo@ejemplo.com">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="tel_fijo">Tel&eacute;fono fijo</label>
                <input type="tel_fijo" class="form-control telefono" name="tel_fijo" id="tel_fijo" placeholder="Tel&eacute;fono fijo">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="tel_cel">Tel&eacute;fono celular</label>
                <input type="tel_cel" class="form-control telefono" name="tel_cel" id="tel_cel" placeholder="Tel&eacute;fono celular">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"> 
              <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                <label class="control-label" for="observaciones">Observaciones</label>
                <textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="5" name="observaciones" id="observaciones"></textarea>
              </div>  
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="idPer" id="idPer">
          </div><!-- End div container -->
        </div><!-- End div modal body -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardarSacerdote">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </form><!-- End form -->
    </div><!-- End div modal content -->
  </div><!-- End div modal dialog -->
</div><!-- End modal Edit -->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
  Open Modal
</button>
```

Take a look on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fru31s3/)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42443566/4131048) for a similar problem (for `show.bs.modal`), one way to solve the isssue is checking `e.target.id`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a bug with the datepicker inside the modal, see issue here [github](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/50).
A workaround is to catch the `hide` event of the datepicker and stop the event from propagating to the modal:

```
$('#fecha_nac').datepicker({
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
      autoclose: true,
      language: 'es'
  }).on('hide', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Updated fiddle:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fru31s3/1/)